# svelte: how do svelte run function between if block?

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte

I am trying to put a function between if else block.
below is what i imagine it would be.:

```svelte
<script>
let condition=false
function function_here(event){
   if(event){
      condition = true;
   }else if(!event){
      condition = false;
   }else{
      condition = !condition;
   }
</script>
{#each post as posts}
   {#if posts.object1==="match" }
      <p>HTML HERE</p>
      {function_here(true)}
   {/if}
{/each}
{#if condition}
   <button>type1</button>
{:else}
   <button>type2</button>
{/if}
```

if only during looping post result, if found posts.object1 match, i need to change the status of variable "condition"

however , this example return result "undefined".

How do i put function in between if block in svelte?

Comment: Can you provide a better example? You are passing `true` to it, so it will always do `condition = true`. I fail to see the purpose of that. And you likely see `undefined` because the function doesn’t `return` anything.

Comment: Maybe what you really want is to compute the value upfront with `condition = posts.some(post => post.object1 === 'match')`

Comment: its one of the first things you should know about javascript. if an function does not return anything, it will return `undefined`. your function doesnt return anything

Comment: hi felix. i need to revert condition back to false, after every post loop. i need to use toggle like function in some other part of code, but in this part, i need to be able to pass true when post.object1 is match. that why the function look like that.

Answer (score 7):

Calling functions inside the template like that is considered bad practice in Svelte, that code belongs in the script part of the component. The best approach this problem is a reactive variable so that it also changes if `posts` changes:

```js
$: condition = posts.... // something based on posts
```

What condition actually works out to be is up to you though, the code you gave in your answer seems very simplified from the actual code.

Comment: are you suggesting doing loop in <script> , pass a posts data into condition first, before do another loop in template? 
If not, then do i run that line in template or <script>?
if in template, i think it will be as same as me trying to put function in template. but if do in script, well, there is no different from using plain js. please correct me if i wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I understand the other answers give a suggestion to use best practices. However, to answer the general question of running or calling JS code in Svelte within the HTML portions of it can be done as follows.

```svelte
<script>
...
</script>

<!-- HTML part -->
{functionCall() || ""}  <-- This avoids 'undefined' showing up in your markup!
```

Or alternatively,

```svelte
<!-- HTML part -->
{"" ?? functionCall()}  <-- This avoids 'undefined' showing up in your markup!
```

Answer (score 2):

Better yet, use the [void](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void) operator.
Using the void and the Nullish operator ensures that, even if your function returns a value, nothing is ever displayed in your markup.

```
<!-- HTML part -->
{void functionCall() ?? ""} <-- This avoids any sort of value from showing up in your markup!
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to approach this in a way that JSX would like. Why not abstract that logic into plain JS inside the `<script>`?

```svelte
<script>
    let condition = false
    function function_here(event) {
        if (event) {
            condition = true;
        } else if (!event) {
            condition = false;
        } else {
            condition = !condition;
        }
    }

    for (post in posts) {
        if (post.object1 === 'match') {
            function_here(true)
        }
    }
</script>
{#each post as posts}
    {#if post.object1 === "match" }
        <p>HTML HERE</p>
    {/if}
{/each}
{#if condition}
    <button>type1</button>
{:else}
    <button>type2</button>
{/if}
```

Comment: i dont think this could work. function cant run outside the same loop block, because  there will be multiple time the condition triggered in actual code.

for every post, i need to convert condition back to false, so that i can properly use toggle function (which are "condition") to work properly.